# How to rename 7-Zip split files as name_00N.zip instead of name.zip.00N

Tags: command-line, batch-file, zip, 7-zip

On Windows, when I create `.zip` split files with volumes less than 20MB with a command like:

```
7z a name.zip files\* -v20M
```

I get one or more files named `name.zip.001`, `name.zip.002`, etc.

I need to rename all `name.zip.00N` to a different naming scheme, which is `name_index.zip` instead of `name.zip.index:`

```
name_001.zip
name_002.zip
name_003.zip
```

Is there an easy way to do this in a `.bat` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple Batch Scripts that execute the task that you have requested:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%l in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
set FILENAME=%%l
set EXTENSION=%%m
set PARTNUMBER=%%n

    if defined PARTNUMBER (
        ren ".\!FILENAME!.!EXTENSION!.!PARTNUMBER!" "!FILENAME!_!PARTNUMBER!.!EXTENSION!
    ) else (
        echo The task cannot be accomplished on file !FILENAME!.!EXTENSION!.
    )

)
pause
```

This script executes a `for` cycle that decomposes the name of each file placed in the folder in which the batch file is launched; it uses the `.` character as a delimiter for the various tokens. Then, if the file name includes three different tokens, it is renamed as in your question's example; otherwise the file is not renamed. This condition allows to exclude the common files with a simple name plus extension from this operation. Unfortunately, I am not sure that 7-Zip will be able to unzip the original file after this renaming.

Comment: Thank you, indeed 7zip (or other program) will not be able to unzip the resulting archives but that's beyond this scope.